# How to save a keras StringLookup object with pickle?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, pickle

I have a computer vision model to break CAPTCHAS. Before running the model I have to map the image labels using the following code:

```py
# Mapping characters to integers
  char_to_num = layers.StringLookup(
  vocabulary=list(characters), mask_token=None)


# Mapping integers back to original characters
  num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
  vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True)
```

Also, the object type of the `char_to_num` object is: `<keras.layers.preprocessing.string_lookup.StringLookup object at 0x00000269799D2C40>`

My problem is that I want to save this mapping so I can use it later when I load the model. Does anyone know how to do that? Maybe using pickle?

Answer (score 0):

`char_to_num.get_vocabulary()` is a list, which you can save in a text file. During inference read the file and create `num_to_char`. You can refer to `app.py` in the demo I have created on HuggingFace spaces [OCR for CAPTCHA](https://huggingface.co/spaces/keras-io/ocr-for-captcha)